# How can I access user's google drive in the server, when he authenticates in the client (node.js)?

Tags: node.js, google-drive-api

I want to create new file in my client's google drive, after some processing in the server. However, I only found ways to get access to the google drive in the client code, for example from [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/js).